# Rendering an image in Rails App hero-unit

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I'm new to Rails and trying to make an image show up as the background of a jumbotron with sass like I would with css, and I'm not sure why it's not working.

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="centerfy">
      <h1>AccessOBD</h1>
      <h2>Do Cars Smarter.</h2>

      <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**static_pages.scss**

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-image: url(app/assets/images/car.jpg);
}
```

with the image obviously in the asset pipeline, but can't get the image to appear. How do I get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is probably that when using the asset pipeline Rails is going to move your file to public/assets and rename it something randomly generated like car-fe48a0ccb8.jpg. The easiest way to get around this is to use one of the sass-rails methods, such as the asset-url helper:

```
background-image: asset-url("car.jpg");
```

Or the image-url helper:

```
background-image: image-url("car.jpg");
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Comment: I tried changing the css to `background-image: image-url(car.jpg);` but I'm getting an error.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: Sorry... should be asset-url, not image-url

Comment: `background-image: asset-url(car.jpg);` is giving me the same error `Invalid CSS after "...: asset-url(car": expected ")", was ".jpg);"`

Comment: My apologizes again - add quotes around car.jpg, or checkout my edited answer.